# Get RTSP stream from live555 and decode with AVFoundation

Tags: avfoundation, qtkit

I need to get video frames from ip camera using RTSP. To get rtsp stream I use live555. The problem is that I can't find a way to decode incoming video frames with AVFoundation. (I can't use ffmpeg). Is there a way to use AVFoundation for video decoding. If yes then how to do it?

Comment: no , there is not, if all you want is extract video frames and you can't use ffmpeg for some reason you might try open-cv (opencv.org), you could also write a rudimentary client in c but it won't be very good.  We use ffmpeg as do most developers of this type of app.

Comment: Michelle Cannon is correct. Given that Video Toolkit is private you do not have direct access to the H.264 hardware. If you were to attempt to do this without using a third party software decoder you could try translating the incoming RTP stream to HTTP Live Streaming or mux it into a QuickTime Streaming File. I would personally try the former. RTP -> HTTP Live Streaming transform and segment -> Embedded HTTP server -> AVFoundation. This does assume you do not need low latency.